# Pillow: Can't draw text with right color in CMYK image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I was using this Pillow code to draw white text on RGB image (PNG format):

```
draw.text((bg_x/2 - 75, 810),
    text=elt_id,
    font=fnt,
    fill="#ffffff")
```

It worked well.
Now, I'm using CMYK mode with TIFF files. The code above drew the text in black instead of white.
I tried to change with the code bellow, but it is still black.

```
draw.text((bg_x/2 - 75, 810),
    text=elt_id,
    font=fnt,
    fill=ImageColor.getcolor("white", "CMYK"))
```

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark Ransom wasn't far from the answer.

`fill=0`(without quotes) is the way to get blank with CMYK image.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a mode to `ImageColor` only works if the mode is grayscale, according to [the documentation](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/ImageColor.html). Don't expect it to convert to CMYK.

CMYK is a subtractive color space, so white is defined as the absence of color, or `#00000000`.

Comment: Thanks for explanations. However, `fill="#00000000"` raises a ValueError, and `fill="#000000"` creates black text. What am I supposed to do to get an actual white text?

Comment: @DavidW. Maybe Pillow is broken. Wouldn't be the first time I've had problems with PIL.

Comment: It seems normal to me that #00000000 raises the `ValueError: unknown color specifier: '#00000000'` since a color code should have 6 digits max, right?